# Rails: Possible to send a disabled option as a valid params value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User, and a Country models, and in User model, it has has_many :countries relationship. The country has 3 attributes -> :id, :name, :is_main

Let's say the countries table is currently populated as follow:

```
id          name          is_main
----------------------------------
1           USA            true
2           Germany        nil
3           France         nil
4           England        nil
```

Let's say a user is created that has countries USA, and Germany. So in this case the user.countries.pluck(:id) would return [1,2].

What I would like to achieve is that when editing the user's countries, a dropdown will appear and I am only allowed to add (or remove) countries where 'is_main' attribute is nil. In other words, in the dropdown, the USA country should either be disabled or be hidden completely to be selected. At the same time, the USA should remain in the user.countries after form submission plus any new countries that have been added from update action.

In short:
Original => user.countries.pluck(:id) => [1,2]

In edit form, if I add France to the user, the end result should be user.countries.pluck(:id) => [1,2,3]

I have tried the following:

```
f.collection_select(:countries, Country.where(is_main: nil), :id, :name, {}, {:multiple => true})
```

In doing this, the dropdown will display all the countries for me to add except for USA, which is what I desired. But the problem is when I click submit, the params[:country_ids] will be [2, 3]. As a result, after update action, the user.countries.pluck(:id) would become [2,3] instead of desired [1,2,3], effectively removing USA's id.

Is there a way to work around this? I have tried also adding :disabled option in collection_select that disables USA option, but the params[:country_ids] would still be [nil, 2, 3]. Appreciate if anyone could advise me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually using your example for multiple selection, your params after submit should have params[:country_ids] = [2,3]. If you are not giving the option to select USA, then it just won't be included.

You can disable options doing this:

```
// Your select id should be 'user_country_ids', if not change it
// This assumes that your first item will always be USA
$('#user_country_ids option:eq(0)').prop('disabled', true);
```

Anyway, this JS can be bypassed, so you will need to handle this on your backend too adding a validation for this in your User model:

```rb
class User
  has_many :countries

  validate :main_countries_always_associateds

  private

  def main_countries_always_associateds
    errors.add(:countries, "must include main ones") if Country.where(is_main: true).any?{ |c| !self.countries.include? c }
  end
end
```

#### EDIT:

**If you want to always have main countries inside each user countries**, then you can use `before_validation` callback to override this selection. I recommend to also include the disabled options on the multiple select, so the user is aware of this, the validation may become not necessary.

```rb
class User
  has_many :countries

  before_validation :associate_main_countries

  # You should use something like this if you want your dropdown to always show marked main countries
  def self.new_custom_user
    User.new(countries: Country.where(is_main: true))
  end

  private

  def associate_main_countries
    Country.where(is_main: true).each do |c|
      self.countries << c if !self.countries.include?(c)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is if i implement such validation, then the code will fail the moment the code performs user update controller action. The main goal is that USA (or other is_main = true countries) should remain after I add new countries to the user. I am not sure if there is a way to hide the USA option value from the dropdown (to prevent from selecting it) but still be able to parse into the params during update action.

Comment: Thank you again. If possible, I prefer not to have a model validation as it is possible that a user may not have a is_main country=true (very rare case but still may happen) or a user may have multiple is_main=true countries. Its just that my example is the common scenario that i will be facing. Ideally, it would be great if there is a way to parse is_main=true countries ids into the params, along with other added countries after sunmitting the edit form.

Comment: It's on you, if you don't need the validation just remove it. Also, if you have cases where users shouldn't have main countries, you will need to customize your `associate_main_countries` to allow this cases

Comment: i agree, will certainly consider your solution. At the moment, i am trying to figure out if this can be done right during the edit form submission

Comment: it's not a good practice to do something like that on you controller, this kind of logic should be on your model

Comment: Sorry, I mean if it is possible to manipulate in views or using helpers. It would be great if somehow the f.collection_select() supports this kind of scenario, or have a way to manipulate the countries input data before passing into collection_select().

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this issue on my application. In rails 4+, set `include_hidden` attribute to `false` in multi-select selet_tags. Here's how i did it.

```
= f.input :countries, as: :select, collection: Country.where(is_main: nil).map{|country| [country.id, country.name]}, input_html: { multiple: true, data: { placeholder: "Countries"} }, include_hidden: false
```

Hope this helps you solve your issue

Comment: Thank you for your answers, unfortunately it doesn't solve the issue. What I would like to achieve is that when the edit form is submitted, the params[:country_ids] should contain [1,2,3], which include USA's country id instead of [2,3] based on the example scenario in my post.